# In React Formik Yup methods for number(), 'round()' method is not working

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have tested the `Yup` method of validation in `Formik` with the following link.

https://codesandbox.io/s/formikyup-number-validation-bug-1f59k

To check the `round` method for `age` I have changed it as

```
validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string()
      .email()
      .required("Required"),
    age: Yup.number()
      .integer()
      .round()
      .default(0) // comment out this line and validation works
      .when("email", (email, schema) => {
        return !!email ? schema.required() : schema;
      })
  })}
```

but it is not working. 
I want to get `3.25` if I type `3.25555` in the age field. I have also tested with `ceil`, `floor` options also but not working.
How can I do this.

Comment: validation is not for that - it checks, not modifies ... use input handler to restrict or format values

Comment: Ok. Thanks @xadm